# c++ rounding special float values to integers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am having some trouble rounding some special float numbers to integers.
I need to round a float number to an integer (if and only if) the first three float point values are zeros or 9's.

For example if the number was 4.0001 I need to round this to 4. and if the number was 4.9998 I need to round it to 5. Other than that, the values should be displayed as they are.

In other words I need to print an integer only if the above two rules were met, otherwise I should print float numbers,

How can one achieve this in C++.

Regards

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I'm not sure how to approach this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're interested in the fractional part, `modf` is your friend.  Say
something like:

```
double
conditionallyRound( double original )
{
    double dummy;
    double frac = modf( fabs( original ), &dummy );
    return frac < 0.001 || frac > 0.999
        ? round( original )
        : original;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `x` should be rounded, then the maximum difference between `x` and `round(x)` will be 0.0001.

Of course, you should be aware that binary floating-point cannot exactly represent 0.0001, so this will always be an approximation.